# iOS RestKit parameters for query

Tags: parameters, mapping, request, restkit

I am trying to GET something from the server, using RestKit.

Let's say I have class A and I want to map returned data to objects, but and i need to append three parameters to request url, for example :

http://example.com/someobject/?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

I have been reading RestKit guide from Github on how to perform mapping of returned objects, seems easy enough, but I simply can't find anything on how to add parameters to the query, most stuff is about outdated 0.10.x library.

Can anyone explain the process?

EDIT:

I mean plain process without using RKClient, but rather RKObjectRequestOperation.

Answer (score 5):

It is very easy to use RKObjectManager in this instance since one can pass in an NSDictionary as the `parameters` argument.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"param1" : @"value1",
                         @"param2" : @"value2",
                         @"param3" : @"value3"};

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:someObject path:nil parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    // success

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // failure

}]
```

Comment: are you familiar with a way to order these parameters for the way it goes into the actual URL requested? For example (see below), in my email my request must have the storeID = 12345 before the isleNume = 2 in the full requested path. Is there a way to do this? Currently the response in the debug shows the params are out of order. Any thoughts? 

{@"storeID" : @"12345", 
@"isleNum" : @"2"}